# Active Records Update can I switch escaping off?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to use the code bellow to update the page count. I'd rather do with one one query, than running one to get the existing count first. Is there a way to tell codeigniter not to escape the query? at the moment it's putting '' around 'page_views + 1' which is breaking the query.

```
 $this->db->where('id', $charity);
 $this->db->update('charities', array('page_views' => 'page_views + 1'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the values like this, it allows disabling escaping

```
$this->db->set('page_views', 'page_views + 1', false);
$this->db->where('id', $charity);
$this->db->update('charities');
```